# Full width background on mobile

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having hard time with an unordered list `ul` full width background on mobile. When I test it with Chrome, full width background shows without any issues (1st image below) but when I check it on my phone, I dont see the background (2nd image below).

The website address is [here](http://chakraco.club/users/olivierhombreux)

[image]

[image]

```
.tabs--primary {
    width: 100%;
    background: #E9E8E8;
    border: none;
    position: relative;
    padding: 15px 0;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    min-height: 60px;
    display: flow-root;
}
.tabs--primary:before, .tabs--primary:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background: #E9E8E8;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 9999px;
}
.tabs--primary:before {
    right: 100%;
}
.tabs--primary:after {
    left: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I've opened it both with chrome devtools on mobile mode and on my oneplus 6 phone, and I don't see this white margin. 
Maybe it's something with your phone's browser?

Comment: My friend just tried it on his iphone X he said he sees the problem too. I have iphone 8.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is an issue relating to iOS Safari, currently not supporting `display: flow-root;`. Most desktop browsers, however, including Chrome, currently support this feature.

This is most likely why you have different results based on if you are viewing the website on your desktop vs your iPhone.

[CanIUse `display: flow-root;`](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flow-root)

Depending on how your CSS is set up you can try just using `display: block;` instead. However, if you are using it as a way to create a new block formatting context you will have to use some workarounds to get it to work. Here's a great article about the [clearfix hack](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/).

Comment: I tried `display: block` and every other way I could find it, still no solution.